# Never used OLEDB, scalar variable error

Tags: vb.net, oledb

I'm trying to get a connection established for an OLEDB connection, but since I've never used it, I don't really know what I am doing wrong. I managed to get a connection in the web.config file, I think, but now I get the 'must declare scalar variable' error. I thought I declared it, but it must be wrong.

```
Private Function GetBackUpAccountName(ByVal BAccount As String, ByRef Name As String) As Boolean
    'sql statement for baccount information in case BAccount is not found, search here next
    Dim backupsql As String = "select * from brokermaster bl WHERE BAccount = @BAccount"
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("BackUpConnectionString").ConnectionString)
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(backupsql, conn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BAccount", BAccount)
            conn.Open()
            Using backuprdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                If (backuprdr.Read) Then
                    Name = backuprdr("Name").ToString()
                    Return True
                Else
                    Return False
                End If
            End Using
            conn.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
End Function

<add name="BackUpConnectionString" 
     connectionString="Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=*******;Initial Catalog=DeskA;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=******;Password=******" 
     providerName="System.Data.OleDb"/>
```

This function is a copy of another function I have on the page for an SQL connection. I have to get account information for clients, and if they are not found in that database, I need to search a different database for them before showing an error. This is the function that works. It's been working for months now and today it was requested that we search another database before the error pops up saying their account was not found.

```
Private Function GetAccountName(ByVal BAccount As String, ByRef FirstName As String, ByRef LastName As String) As Boolean
    'sql statement for baccount information
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT BAccount, First_Name, Last_Name FROM IB inner join IB_BUISNESS_INFORMATION ON (IB.IB_ID = IB_BUISNESS_INFORMATION.IB_ID) WHERE BAccount = @BAccount"
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("IBConnectionString").ConnectionString)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BAccount", BAccount)
            conn.Open()
            Using rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                If (rdr.Read) Then
                    FirstName = rdr("First_Name").ToString()
                    LastName = rdr("Last_Name").ToString()
                    Return True
                Else
                    Return False
                End If
            End Using
            conn.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: You should use SqlClient instead of OleDb; it's faster.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I've never used this before so I just tried to make something work when I did a Google search. :/

Comment: Basically, replace every occurrence of `OleDb` with `SqlClient` and use a direct SQL Server connection string.  Right now, you're going through the OLE DB wrapper, which is slower.

Comment: Also, you can call `ExecuteScalar` instead of `ExecuteReader` to make your code much simpler.

Comment: The OLEDB provider for SQL Server might be burping on the parameter name.  Try replacing @BAccount with just a ? in both the sql text and the parameter call.  Not 100% that is the problem.

Comment: What does the `?` do? I replaced them and it stops there when debugging and says `Incorrect Syntax near '?'.` Also @SLaks, I tried replacing `ExecuteReader` with `ExecuteScalar` and got an error. I must not have replaced it correctly.

Comment: OLEDB doesn't use names, just an index, and the ? is used as an index marker.  For the SQL, change it to `BAccount = ?` and for the parameter, change it to `.AddWithValue("?", BAccount)`.  SLaks did not intend to say swap ExecuteReader with ExecuteScalar, but call it instead.  It's a different type of call, but for what you are doing, more efficient.  It would require changing your code.

Comment: I would mask the value of the Data Source in the connection string too in any public posts.

Comment: I will look into ExecuteScalar and see how I can change the code. I added the ? and then replaced them with @BAccount again and somehow rerunning it after replacing with ? made it work....how odd. Well it sort of works....it gets the right name when I am watching it in debugger, but it displays a different name. I added IS NOT NULL to the end of the statement, but it still shows wrong information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OleDB uses positional parameters. Do this...

```
Dim backupsql As String = "select * from brokermaster bl WHERE BAccount = ?"
```

And posting your data source value of your connection string in public posts is risky business.

Comment: Oh whoops! I had a feeling I was forgetting something. The ?s just added syntax errors so I replaced them with @BAccount and this time it worked. It is displaying the wrong name, but in debug mode it shows the right name is being pulled.